# relative positioning, margin auto, and an img as a block

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I have centered with `display: block;` and `margin: auto;` that I am trying to have partially overlap the div below it. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code, and I can't find any info on the net (I really searched!). I hate to ask, but can I even mix position relative and margin auto? Is that what the problem is? Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>        
    <img class='img-circle bio_pic' src='img/Matthew_bio_fin.jpg'>    
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Hi! I'm ...!</h1>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bio_pic {
    width: 190px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    border: solid green 4px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 80;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve.. this is the output.. http://jsfiddle.net/G9Fxs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing units:

```
top: 80px;
```